# start and stop the service of notificationlistener

Tags: android, service

How can I start and stop the service of NotificationListener for Android?

I want to start the service at a specific time and also want to stop it at a specific time.

How is it possible?

(I'm asking about the [NotificationListener](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example) library.)

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As the NotificationListenerService is a kind of Service, you are able to start or stop it like any other Service, e.g.

you first extend NotificationListenerService

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {...}
```

and implement the callbacks you need.
Please make sure to edit your Manifest as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Now you can start your Service by calling

```
startService(new Intent(com.example.servicedemo.NotificationListener));
```

(where of course you have to substitute com.example... by your own package name :) )

For stopping just call

```
stopService(new Intent(...));
```

Comment: OS is responsible of starting and stopping NotificationListenerService when you enable it in settings: android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS. startService() and stopService() has no effect

Answer (score 0):

NotificationListenerService is a special kind of service, and it is started/stopped by the system, when it is selected/deselected in the "Notification access" settings screen. You can create a "shortcut" to this method doing something like this:

```
Intent intentS = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intentS);
```

Also, if you are doing development work, you want to make sure you uncheck notification access in the settings BEFORE deploying a new version to the phone. In my experience, if you don't, you'll need to reboot your phone before your service will start working again.

Comment: "you want to make sure you uncheck notification access in the settings BEFORE deploying a new version to the phone". In other words if you update your application on play store, it will no longer work

Comment: @ClassA might as well give it a try, YMMV. I think I was using MM and maybe nougat/oreo handle it better